# It says "ftp localhost command not found" .when I login as anonymous user in linux using command ftp localhost

Tags: linux

It says "**ftp localhost command not found"** .when I login as anonymous user in linux using command ftp localhost.

Comment: While I realize that English may not be your native language, the sentence above makes no sense.  What are you logging into?  What are you logging into it from? How are you logging in as "anonymous user"?  Which machine is giving the error "ftp localhost command not found"?

Comment: Please copy&paste the text from the terminal into your question so we can see exactly what you did + the error message. There is a `{}` button at the top of the question editor which allows you to turn the text into a code block. For this, select the pasted text and click the button.

Comment: Do you have an `ftp` program installed on the computer? It sounds like maybe you need to install an ftp client on the computer (and a server since you are trying to log into the same box).

Comment: @hymie I am logging into my linux virtual machine as a root user.I have logged in as anonymous user in order to use ftp services.Whenever I type command 'ftp localhost' it says command not found.

Comment: @JNevill, yes I have vsftpd package installed on my computer.

Comment: How do you "login as anonymous user" on a linux virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

The `ftp` server doesn't support the command `ftp`. That means after logging in as `anonymous` via your FTP client, you now have to use the FTP commands (`get`, `put`, `ls`, ...). You can't start `ftp` again inside from an FTP client.

If you want to connect to a different FTP server without leaving your FTP client, you can use the command `open`.